# resumable-create-media link

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I'm creating an iOS app that will upload a file to a specific collection in Google Docs. How can I get the resumable-create-media link for that collection?

When I do a get request on the collection as recommended here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-documents-list-api/LOxHfIxVAec

I get the following xml (sadly no resumable-create-media)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
         xmlns:docs='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007' 
         xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch' 
         xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
     <id>https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full/folder%3A0B4Xm3k31FF25MXZzbjZvNzhZU00</id>
     <published>2012-07-03T14:38:35.068Z</published>
     <updated>2012-07-03T14:38:35.068Z</updated>
     <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#folder' label='folder'/>
     <title type='text'>My Collection</title>
     <content type='application/atom+xml' src='https://docs.google.com/feeds/folders/private/full/folder%3A0B4Xm3k31FF25MXZzbjZvNzhZU00'/>
     <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://docs.google.com/#folders/folder.0.0B4Xm3k31FF25MXZzbjZvNzhZU00'/>
     <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#icon' type='image/png' href='https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_9_collection_list.png'/>
     <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full/folder%3A0B4Xm3k31FF25MXZzbjZvNzhZU00'/>
     <link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full/folder%3A0B4Xm3k31FF25MXZzbjZvNzhZU00/h47320jg'/>
     <author><name>xxxx</name>
     <email>xxxx@gmail.com</email></author>
     <gd:resourceId>folder:0B4Xm3k31FF25MXZzbjZvNzhZU00</gd:resourceId>
     <gd:lastModifiedBy><name>stayaway</name><email>xxxx@gmail.com</email></gd:lastModifiedBy>
     <gd:quotaBytesUsed>0</gd:quotaBytesUsed>
     <docs:writersCanInvite value='true'/>
     <gd:feedLink rel='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessControlList' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/acl/private/full/folder%3A0B4Xm3k31FF25MXZzbjZvNzhZU00'/>
</entry>
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) has replaced the Documents List API.

A sample Objective-C application that demonstrates use of the Drive API, including uploading and downloading files, is [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/DriveSample/DriveSampleWindowController.m).

Comment: I ended up doing the same myself. Thanks Greg